# example of injective dimension of finitely generated module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples, homological-algebra, injective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative local ring. $M$ and $N$ are two finitely generated $R$-module of finite injective dimension.

I want to fine an example of $M$ and $N$ such that
$injdim(M)\neq injdim(N)$

Does anyone know?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $R$ is noetherian, there is no such example.
Indeed, consider Theorem 18.9 from Matsumura's book commutative ring theory:

Theorem: Let (R,m) be a commutative noetherian local ring, and let M be a non-zero finitely generated A-module. If the injective dimension of M is finite, then it is equal to depth(A).